# Postman post request field must not be empty

Tags: json, postman, http-status-code-422

```json
{"active":true,"name":"webhook","resource":{"type":"CONTACT"}}
```

I'm sending this in raw body in postman but getting this eror

```json
    "status": 422,
    "errors": [
        {
            "field": "resource.desks",
            "cause": "must not be empty"
        }
```

How can I add this field to body

I've tried these;

```json
{"active":true,"name":"webhook","resource":{"type":"CONTACT", "desk":"me"}}

{"active":true,"name":"webhook","resource":{"type":"CONTACT"}, "desk":"me"}

{"active":true,"name":"webhook","resource":{"type":"CONTACT"}, "resource.desks":"me"}

{"active":true,"name":"webhook","resource":{"type":"CONTACT", "resource.desks":"me"}}
```

But I'm still getting the same error

Comment: At the risk of pointing out the obvious, `"desk"` is not `"desks"`

Comment: `{"active":true,"name":"webhook","resource":{"type":"CONTACT", "desks":"me"}}` maybe?

Comment: Ohhh It says desks, so should I send a list like "desks":["me"]